# ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2100 source not found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Ive started developing an app and i havent changed the class, nor changed the manifest, only created the xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#111111"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Playing" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlcontrols"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bplay"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvalbum"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:contentDescription="@+String/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bprevious"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvalbum"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bplay"
        android:background="@drawable/previous"
        android:contentDescription="@+String/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bnext"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvalbum"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bplay"
        android:background="@drawable/next"
        android:contentDescription="@+String/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/brepeat"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bnext"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bnext"
        android:background="@drawable/repeat"
        android:contentDescription="@+String/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bshuffle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bprevious"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bprevious"
        android:background="@drawable/shuffle"
        android:contentDescription="@+String/play" />

    <!-- <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seeker"
        android:layout_below="@id/bplay" /> -->

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvalbum"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rlcontrols"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/album"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvartist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/tvalbum"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/artist"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/tvartist"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivalbumart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/tvtitle"
    android:contentDescription="@+String/albumart"
    android:src="@drawable/albumart" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Debug stack:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2100    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2125 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 140    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1227  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4898    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1006 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 773 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Saying source not found when i launch the activity

I've no idea what this means so any help would be great thanks

Comment: Show some more of the logs, and it would be more clear.

Comment: post full stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Without your project I can only guess but typically this is caused by the Manifest file not being correct.  Make sure your package is correct and then you need to call out your activities similar to

```
<activity
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:name=".MyLaunchActivity" >
     <intent-filter >
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <activity android:name=".My_Second_Activity" >
 </activity>
```

Comment: My manifest is correct and exactly as you put. I've searched my entire project and found nothing out of order :/

Answer (score 1):

were you trying to debug your code? I had a similar issue looks like You are missing Android Vx.jar file's source code..
Refer this link it might help you.
http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/

Answer (score 1):

I got through a similar problem just because I missed the appcompat_v7 library. In my case, let's say that the name of my project is Prj_A.
 To know wich librairy PrjA needs, you have to read the project.properties file (see the root of the project).

For all resources mentioned in the project.properties file, you need to add that library. Let's say Lib_1, Lib_2 ... Lib_n
That mean you have to import "as android project" each Lib_x requested by the project.properties file from Prj_A and then go to the Prj_A , right-click, Properties, Android. A window popup rises,see the frame at the bottom showing libraries of the Prj_A. Make sure you have a green mark in front each libraries mentioned.

For all libraries with a red question mark on it OR for each missing libraries, you need to perform the following step into the frame showing Libraries:
Click on the Add button, it will popup a window containing all libraries candidates (i.e. IMPORTED and OPEN in your workspace).
If your don't have libraries, you are looking for you need to import AND open those in your workspace first.

Then each library with a red question mark on it needs to be removed. So into the frame showing Libraries, click on the library with red "?" and click the remove button. Then click apply.